# Filtering custom HTML list

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with filtering a customer list which is grouped by first letters.
The code below is used in html site.

```
<ul id="fil" >
 <input type="text" id="input" />

<li id ="group">S</li>
 <li>
<a class="name">sen</a> 
</li>
 <li>
<a class="name">ser</a> 
</li>
<li id ="group">l</li>
 <li>
<a class="name">l</a> 
</li>
```

The function I used for filter is below

```
var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
var lis = document.getElementById('fil').getElementsByTagName('li');
var name='';

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

    if ( lis[i].className =='') 
    {           
        name = lis[i].getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerHTML;

        if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0  )
            lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
        else
            lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

My problem is when I start to type letters, for example("s"), it filters all the group classes (also "l") and "ser" and "sen".

All I just want to do is to filter its first letter and the rest of the letters that I type.

Thank you...

Comment: FYI, the `id` attribute in HTML must be unique. You may not have more than one element with an ID of "group".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my spin on it; it takes the full value into account, not just the first letter.

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/9da819a878bf7edcbd1972529d03dd43)

[image: List filter]

```
  var lis = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#fil > li:not(.group)')),
      input = document.getElementById('input'),
      liText,
      hasText,
      len;

  input.onkeyup = function () {
    var value = input.value.toUpperCase(),
        i = 0;
    
    for (len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
      liText = lis[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
      hasText = liText.substr(0, value.length) == value;
      lis[i].style.display = hasText
                               ? 'list-item'
                               : 'none';
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is  what I do at the moment; I don't want to filter groups except I type.. when you filter "L"; I want to omit "s" group title...Think a list a-z. :(

Comment: li:not(.group)') =>>>>li:not(.name)') :)

Comment: I see how that does what you want, now. lol. with just a small change.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, looks like it's pretty much what you need.

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('input');
var lis = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#fil > li:not(.group)'));

function getGroupByLetter(char) {
    return lis.filter(function(li) {
        return li.textContent.trim()[0] === char;
    });
}

filter.onkeyup = function() {
    getGroupByLetter(this.value[0]).forEach(function(li) {
        li.style.display = li.textContent.indexOf(filter.value) !== -1 ? '' : 'none';
    });
};
```

```css
.group {background: #EEE;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<ul id="fil">
    <li class="group">S</li>
    <li><a class="name">sli</a></li>
    <li><a class="name">sen</a></li>
    <li><a class="name">ser</a></li>
    <li class="group">L</li>
    <li><a class="name">last</a></li>
    <li><a class="name">lite</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9c1g9fr6/2/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input").on("keypress keyup", function(e) {
        var value = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        filterText($("#input"),value); });
});

function filterText(input, text)
{    
    var lis = $(input).closest('#fil').find('li');
    var lisItem = $(input).closest('#fil').find('.name');

    $(lis).css("display", "list-item");

    if(text != "")
    {
        var filter = text.toUpperCase();
        var name='';

        $(lisItem).each(function() {

                name = $(this).html().toUpperCase();

                if (name[0] == filter)
                    $(this).closest("li").css("display", "list-item");
                else 
                    $(this).closest("li").css("display", "none");
        });
    }
}
```